# Rails schema to xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xsd

is there any built in way in rails to convert a model schema into an XML schema , (witch i need to interface with crystal reports)

any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out the [ARDumper plugin](http://www.railslodge.com/plugins/1509-ar-dumper) which will let you export the **data** within the model.

If you want the actual fields in your model you'll need to write an export off of the model.